# Read text file and find unique records

Tags: text-processing

I have a large text file with columns A, B, C, and D. How do I read the unique values for columns C and D and write those unique rows to a regular text file or in JSON format?

Comment: Please post a row so I can see the dorm of the text for process by regular expression.

Comment: As Tyler said, please show us an example of your input and desired output. Do both C and D need to be unique? Do you mean unique combinations of C+D? Would `foo bar` be the same as `bar foo`?

Comment: A    B    C         D

q    a    ENT123    New York
b    c    ENT123    New York
d    e    ENT345    New Jersy
f    n    ENT345    New Jersy
x    y    ENT346    New Hampshire
w    p    ENT346    New Hampshire   file looks like this and below is the expected result

Comment: C         D

ENT123    New York
ENT345    New Jersy
ENT346    New Hampshire

Comment: I hope my example makes sense for what I am requesting.

Comment: Edit your examples into your question: they are too hard to read as comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
sort -k 3,5 -u yourFile.txt | awk '{output = $3; for(i=4; i<=NF; i++) output = output " " $(i); print output;}'
```

where option -k sets columns C and D as key, -u unique and awk prints columns C and D.